# OR and confidence interval in glmer not working for my model

Tags: lme4, confidence-interval

I have fitted the following model:

```r
cn_sign.mod3 <- glmer(sign ~ time + gmc_secident + time*gmc_cn + 
    (time|id), US_mlm, family = "binomial", 
     control = glmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore"))
```

The model itself works but I have problems calculating the odds ratio and confidence interval. I have tried using `lme4::confint.merMod(cn_sign.mod3)` and tried boosting `devtol =`  but even with `devtol = 1e-01` (I went down stepwise) it doesn't work (I took this from here: [Error when estimating CI for GLMM using confint()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53120614/error-when-estimating-ci-for-glmm-using-confint))

For the odds ratio I have tried:

```r
cc_cn_sign.mod3 <- confint(cn_sign.mod3, parm = "beta_")
ctab_cn_sign.mod3 <- cbind(est=fixef(cn_sign.mod3),cc_cn_sign.mod3)
rtab_ccn_sign.mod3 <- exp(ctab_cn_sign.mod3)
print(rtab_cn_sign.mod3, digits = 3)
```

as well as

```r
or.glmer(US_mlm, cn_sign.mod3, complex)
```

(from https://rdrr.io/github/mjwestgate/sppairs/man/or.glmer.html)

but nothing seems to work. My DV is very uneven (with 1 = `N` of 15, and 0 = `N` of 89) and I am afraid that this influences the functionality of this model?

Comment: can you edit your question to give the specific error encountered? (the linked answer suggests what it is, but it would be nice if your question were self-contained)

Comment: Is there any chance  we can have a [mre]? In this case it probably means providing your full data set ...